# WPF DataGrid filter based on other column filter selections

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 3 columns and each one has a filter button that brings up a ListBox that contains CheckBox items.

By themselves each column filters my DataGrid was well as I expected it to be. But, my problem is that now I can't get my DataGrid to filter properly. Each column filter is overriding the other one. In other words... if I pick filter items from ColumnHeader1 and then select filter items from ColumnHeader2 then the filters from ColumnHeader1 get overridden event though they still appear selected in the GUI.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I'm utilizing an `ICollectionView` object and added my `DataGrid.ItemSource` to it.

This is where I'm having the issue and is on my `OnFilterTriggered` method:

```
public bool OnFilterTriggered(object item)
        {
            // Get the list of all the filter columns
            var filter_list_1_selected = FilterListOne.Where(filterItem => filterItem.IsChecked == true).Select(filter => filter.Name).ToList();
            var filter_list_2_selected = FilterListTwo.Where(filterItem => filterItem.IsChecked == true).Select(filter => filter.Name).ToList();
            var filter_list_3_selected = FilterListThree.Where(filterItem => filterItem.IsChecked == true).Select(filter => filter.Name).ToList();

            if (filter_list_1_selected.Count > 0 || 
                filter_list_2_selected.Count > 0 ||
                filter_list_3_selected.Count > 0)
            {
                if (item is MyDataRowModel dataRow)
                {
                    return (filter_list_1_selected.Contains(dataRow.Name) 
                        || filter_list_2_selected.Contains(dataRow.CustomerId) 
                        || filter_list_3_selected.Contains(dataRow.Status));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Each of these rows have string values so that's why I'm utilizing the `Contains` extension method. My question is this: how do I get all these list to work in tandem so that my DataGRid filters properly?